# Laravel optional parameter missing required parameters

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
```

I created a two routes.

First one for all products, other for categories.

I got an error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: products] [URI:
>   products/{category}/{page?}].

It is laravel: 5.5

I am calling all products like this:

```
{{ route('products') }}
```

Comment: You have two routes named products. That's going to cause an issue. Routes should have unique names.

Comment: two routes cannot have same names try changing the name of the routes

Comment: your routes will follow only first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route name like

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.category');
```

For Product route:

```
{{ route('products') }}
```

For category route:

```
{{ route('product.category') }}
```

Comment: @Nevermore You should use like `{!! route('products', ['page' => $prev] ) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

Your route naming clashes, you will need to give your routes unique names.

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products.page');
Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products.category.page');
```

Call the route with the new name.

```
{{ route('products.page') }}
```

If you want to get the route for for the route with the category parameter.

```
{{ route('products.category.page', $category) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two routes cannot have same names and you are doing this.
Change your routes name to:

```
Route::get('/products/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/products/{category}/{page?}', 'ProductController@index')->name('category.products');
```

and then you can call te routes like:

```
{{ route('products') }}
{{ route('category.products', ['category' => $category->id) }}
```

Thanks.